# Python : class variable gets modified for new object as well

Tags: python

```
class TrialDetails:
    trial_number: int
    def __init__(self, trial_number=-1):
        self.trial_number = trial_number
    def set_trial_number(self, trial_number):
        self.trial_number = trial_number
class HpoExperiment:
    experiment_name: str
    total_trials: int
    trialDetails: object
    def __init__(self, experiment_name, total_trials, trialDetails = TrialDetails()):
        self.experiment_name = experiment_name
        self.total_trials = total_trials
        self.trialDetails = trialDetails
    def set_trial(self, trial_number):
        self.trialDetails.set_trial_number(trial_number)
    def display(self):
        print ("exp name = ", self.experiment_name)
        print ("total trials = ", self.total_trials)
        print ("trial number = ", self.trialDetails.trial_number)

def main():
    exp1 = HpoExperiment("A", 5)
    exp2 = HpoExperiment("B", 3)
    print("Experiment Details")
    exp1.display()
    exp2.display()
    print("Update Experiment 1")
    exp1.set_trial(22)
    print("Experiment Details")
    exp1.display()
    exp2.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While running the above code, why does the value of exp2 object also gets modified?
I want to keep it separate for each object. Unable to understand how to do that.

Comment: Because it is a **class** variable and not an **instance** variable. Leave them out of the class body.

Comment: There are no *class variables* here, only class-level type hints, which is okay (though somewhat redundant). It's *mutable default arguments* again…

Comment: Although the comments are correct: you were defining class attributes (if you'd assign them values - which you didn't, currently they were just type hints), the real issue is what's described in the linked question - you were providing a mutable default value with `trialDetails = TrialDetails()` in the constructor definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way you initialize `trialDetails` in your constructor:

```py
def __init__(self, experiment_name, total_trials, trialDetails = TrialDetails()):
```

You may think that on each call the `trialDetails` gets initialized to new instance of your `TrialDetails` class, but it is not the case, as
default argument is bond to function definition. Because of this you get the same instance for your both `HpoExperiment` objects, which you can easily verify by adding plain `print(trialDetails)` to `__init__()`. The solution would be to move initialization of the `trialDetails` to constructor body, i.e.:

```py
def __init__(self, experiment_name, total_trials, trialDetails = None):
    if not trialDetails:
       trialDetails = TrialDetails()
    ...
```

After that change you got two instances and expected outcome:

```bash
Experiment Details
exp name =  A
total trials =  5
trial number =  -1
exp name =  B
total trials =  3
trial number =  -1

Update Experiment 1
Experiment Details
exp name =  A
total trials =  5
trial number =  22
exp name =  B
total trials =  3
trial number =  -1
```